# Range Markers using Google Chart tool

Tags: svg, google-visualization

I am trying to highlight ranges or areas of a graph in Google Chart api. I need both lines and areas. I found documentation for it in the deprecated version of Google Chart with static images ([link](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params#gcharts_range_markers)), but I can't find any documentation on how to do it in the new version. This is what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a ComboChart to get multiple different types of series into one chart.  You need an "area" series to get the colored area.  There are a few different ways to get a vertical line, but given that you're already going to have to use a ComboChart to make the colored area, you might as well use the same technique to draw the vertical line.  Here's some sample code that creates a chart like this:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Area');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Vertical Line');
    data.addRows([
        [1, 5, null, null],
        [2, 4, null, null],
        [3, 6, null, null],
        [4, 2, null, null],
        [5, 2, null, null],
        [6, 5, null, null],
        [7, 8, null, null],
        [8, 9, null, null],
        [9, 3, null, null],
        [10, 6, null, null],
        // add data for the area background
        // start of area:
        [5, null, 0, null], // make sure the bottom value here is as low or lower than the min value you want your chart's y-axis to show
        [5, null, 10, null], // make sure the top value here is as high or higher than the max value you want your chart's y-axis to show
        // end of area:
        [8, null, 10, null], // use the same max value as the start
        [8, null, 0, null], // use the same min value as the start
        // add data for line:
        [3, null, null, 0], // use the same min value as the area
        [3, null, null, 10] // use the same max value as the area
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        series: {
            0: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            1: {
                // area series
                type: 'area',
                enableInteractivity: false,
                lineWidth: 0
            },
            2: {
                // vertical line series
                type: 'line',
                enableInteractivity: false
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                // you may want to set min/max here, depending on your data and the min/max used for your area and vertical line series
            }
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/FEy4W/